# Modify img attribut src

Tags: php, preg-replace

Here is what I have

```
<img src="http://some.site.com/v/b/image-name/_thumb_100x100.jpg">
```

I'm trying to modify the src by replacing the size to `_thumb_200x200.jpg`

i tried `preg_replace()` but nothing .

Comment: Why not modify the template to put it to 200x200 in the first place, rather than running an unnecessary PHP function?

Comment: haahha he might have a decent reason for not doing that, any way I would recommend looking into php DOM and loadHTML functions it will let you query your HTML and modify it without getting into regular expressions, really depends on your needs, in case this is not the only image you need to make modifications on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have that code in a string, you can use str_replace:

```
$str = str_replace('_thumb_100x100.jpg', '_thumb_200x200.jpg', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with preg_replace

```
$src="http://some.site.com/v/b/image-name/_thumb_100x100.jpg";

echo preg_replace('/_thumb_100x100.jpg/','_thumb_200x200.jpg',$src);
```